# How can I place a link to flag a user inside an e-mail sent by rules?

Tags: rules, flags

I have an "abuse" flag and I want users to be able to flag abusive users via e-mail. I have been [consulting the documentation for adding flag links to pages](http://drupal.org/node/295383).

Problem No. 1: I can't get the link to generate properly in the message.  My code, placed in the **Message** field of the rules **Send mail** action, looks like this:

```
REPORT ABUSE:
<?php
$account = $node->uid;
print flag_create_link('abuse', $account); ?>
```

The `$node` variable is provided for PHP evaluation by the rules module itself.  I checked the value of `$node->uid` by printing it out and it is printing the correct UID value.

However, this generates a link that looks like this:
`flag/flag/abuse/6?destination=node/add/ad-reply%3Ffield_reply_orig_node%3D7&amp;token=EYchAT6nusUXcMtnoLwA2vrGb5bphDX0oGQmjBV3LC4`

And gives the error:

> Bad token. You seem to have followed an invalid link.

How can I print a flag link in the e-mail?

Problem No. 2: E-mails are sent in plaintext, but `flag_create_link()` generates an HTML link.  At worst, I can live with this.

Comment: Hi Patrick, were you able find any solution for this? I have a very similar problem. I've posted my question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95289/how-to-add-a-flag-link-in-an-email

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. No luck yet, unfortunately.

Comment: I've done it with a dirty workaround. I changed the link type to 'confirmation form', so that the link works without token. Then, I hardcoded the link in the mail template, like `<a href="<?php print $base_url . base_path() . 'flag/confirm/flag/FLAG_NAME/' . $nid; ?>">Flag this node</a>`